# Printing The Lowest Number From An Array Using DO UNTIL LOOP

Tags: qbasic

I'm writing a QBasic program that will receive the marks of 10 students using DO UNTIL loop and compute the lowest mark, but my program always seems to  freeze when I run it and enter the 10 students marks.

I tried everything that I know to, but it still freezes anyway.

Below is my code:

```
DIM arr(10) AS INTEGER
DIM low AS INTEGER
DIM x AS INTEGER

CLS
x = 0
DO UNTIL x >= 10
    INPUT "Enter Number: ", arr(x)
    x = x + 1
LOOP

low = arr(1)

DO UNTIL x >= 11
    IF arr(x) < low THEN
        low = arr(x)
    END IF
LOOP

CLS 

PRINT "All Marks Are:"
PRINT arr(x); " ";

PRINT
PRINT "The Lowest Number is: "; low
```

And I'm expecting results below:

```
All Marks Are:
54 32 59 43 90 43 12 4 54 35

The Lowest Number is: 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I would change a couple things in your code.  First of all,

```
DO UNTIL x >= 10
    INPUT "Enter Number: ", arr(x)
    x = x + 1
LOOP
```

Why use a DO ... LOOP here?  I'd opt for a FOR loop:

```
FOR x = 1 to 10
  INPUT "Enter Number: ", arr(x)
NEXT
```

It's more conventional, shorter code, and overall cleaner.

Secondly, your second DO ... LOOP has no way of exiting.  Yeah, sure, it exits when x is greater than or equal to 11, but when's that going to happen?  There's no redefining of x going on in your loop, so your loop is either infinite (if x starts out less than 11) or meaningless (if x is already 11 or greater).  In this case, x will equal 10 at this point, so your code will, as you described, freeze.

The parsing you're trying to do is unfortunately excessively complex in QBasic, but it is possible. For clarity, at the top of your program define `TRUE` and `FALSE`:

```
CONST TRUE = 1
CONST FALSE = 0
```

Then when you come to the place where you want to parse for the smallest value, do something along these lines:

```
finished% = TRUE 'I start by defining as TRUE and define as FALSE if I find
                 'a value which is smaller than the currently tested value.

CurTest% = 1 'This represents the array element which I am currently testing.
             'It will change only when the program finds a value smaller than
             'the one it is currently testing.

DO
  finished% = TRUE
  FOR i = CurTest% + 1 TO 10
    IF arr(i) < arr(CurTest%) THEN
      finished% = FALSE
      CurTest% = i
      EXIT FOR
    END IF
  NEXT i
LOOP UNTIL finished% = TRUE

'The loop will only complete once it has gone through a complete FOR...NEXT
'without finding a smaller value.

PRINT "The smallest value is:"; arr(CurTest%)
```

*N.B.: Code is untested; there may be quirks / bugs.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your code slightly for low score results in this:

```
DIM arr(10) AS INTEGER
DIM low AS INTEGER
DIM x AS INTEGER

CLS
x = 1
DO UNTIL x > 10
    INPUT "Enter Number: ", arr(x)
    x = x + 1
LOOP

low = arr(1)
x = 1
DO UNTIL x > 10
    IF arr(x) < low THEN
        low = arr(x)
    END IF
    x = x + 1
LOOP

CLS
PRINT "All Marks Are:"
FOR x = 1 TO 10
    PRINT arr(x); " ";
NEXT

PRINT
PRINT "The Lowest Number is: "; low
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to set `x` back to 0 (or use a different variable) before your 2nd loop. Because it will continue incrementing `x` from where you left off with the 1st loop.

It also might run into problems with the 2nd loop because your array takes only 10 integers, but you are trying to access the 11th position in the array.

Answer (score 0):

More efficient way of determining lowest score in 10 items:

```
REM determine lowest score of 10 items
CLS
FOR x = 1 TO 10
    PRINT "Enter Number"; x;: INPUT arr(x)
    IF x = 1 THEN low = arr(x)
    IF arr(x) < low THEN
        low = arr(x)
    END IF
NEXT
PRINT "All Marks Are:"
FOR x = 1 TO 10
    PRINT arr(x); " ";
NEXT
PRINT
PRINT "The Lowest Number is: "; low
```

Answer (score 0):

Another sample to determine highest/lowest/average scores of any number of items:

```
REM determine highest/lowest/average score of any number of items
CLS
PRINT "Number of items";: INPUT n
DIM arr(n) AS SINGLE
FOR x = 1 TO n
    PRINT "Enter Number"; x;: INPUT arr(x)
    IF x = 1 THEN low = arr(x): high = arr(x)
    avg = avg + arr(x)
    IF arr(x) < low THEN
        low = arr(x)
    END IF
    IF arr(x) > high THEN
        high = arr(x)
    END IF
NEXT
PRINT "All Marks Are:"
FOR x = 1 TO n
    PRINT arr(x);
NEXT
PRINT
PRINT "The Highest Number is:"; high
PRINT "The Lowest Number is:"; low
PRINT "The Average of all Scores is:"; avg / n
```